# Efficient way to check requisites to get an ability for a role-playing-game platform

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a Role-Playing-Game Web Platform to manage in-game characters. I'm using PHP and MySql. 
    Here is my problem : i need an efficient and easy way to check if a player has the requisites to get an ability.I just need an hint to structure the database.Currently here is the DB structure(just the necessary part to resolve my problem):

Abilities:

This table stores my abilities.

`|Ability ID|Name|Cost|`

Competences :

This table stores, for each character, what are his abilities.

`|Character ID(references the character)|Ability ID(references the ability id)|`

When a character tries to learn a new ability, i need to check if it knows the required abilities to learn the new one.
I need to check things like(for example):

```
Swords && Shield
Swords && almost 2 of the following : (Alchemy,Potions,Brawling,Archery)
Swords || ( Archery && Fencing)
```

What's the best way to store those requirements? Thank you

Comment: The `rpg` tag is for the Report Program Generator programming language, not Role-Playing Games.

Comment: If that is the finite and complete list of possible abilities, I would make a column for each thing and store a date of completion or something.  If this list may increase or change, I would store it as key value pairs.  That table would have the fields table_row_id, user_id, ability(_id), date_of_completion, etc...

Comment: I'd need to see a more comprehensive data set before I could say.

Comment: I doubt if MySQL would be the right tool for calculating game logic like this. As a matter of fact, the same goes for PHP.

Comment: @GolezTrol Neither MySQL nor PHP would be a limitation here.  Having the proper way of modelling such rules is the key thing here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with less than two additional tables in a fully normalized fashion.

```
Table: prerequisites
abilityid  Points to the ability table primary key
prereqid   Primary key of this table
prereqtype AND or OR, essentially

Table: prereq_elements
prereqid   Points to prerequisites table
abilityid  Points to ability table
```

Each entry in the prerequisites table defines a requirement need to purchase the ability referenced by `abilityid`. That 'requirement' is defined as a set of things referenced in the `prereq_elements` table. If the prereq type is 'and', every ability referenced in `prereq_elements` must be possessed by the character for the prereq to be satisfied. If it is 'or', any one of the abilities will do.

Comment: Thought the same solution...but how could i apply prerequisites like :

Archery && 3 of the following(Ability 1,Ability 2,Ability 3,Ability 4,Ability 5,Ability 6) with a simple AND/OR prereqtype? :)

Comment: At that juncture, I think you're beyond what can be elegantly done in MySQL. You want to pull in the prerequisite groups (Archery and 3 of (x group)) to your php and have different deciders instead of AND/OR. So, the ChooseThree decider will see if there are three appropriate skills owned by the character that have been pulled in. If so it returns 'satisfied'.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a manageable number of abilities, you might consider looking at each one as a bit-wise integer value and using a bitmask to determine if specific requirements are met.  This might be presented best with example tables:

abilities:

```
ability_id  name         bit_value cost
1           swords       1         ?
2           shield       10        ?
3           alchemy      100       ?
4           potions      1000      ?
5           brawling     10000     ?
6           archery      100000    ?
7           fencing      1000000   ?
8           new ability  10000000  ?
```

ability_bitmasks

```
   bitmask_id  bitmask      notes
   1            11            swords && shield
   2            101           swords && alchemy
   3            1001          swords && potions
   4            10001         swords && brawling
   5            100001        swords && archery      
   6            1             swords
   7            1100000       archery && fencing
```

Note that I am showing both `swords` and `archery && fencing` related to your suggested rule of `swords || (archery && fencing)` This rule however does not make logical sense as this renders all the other requirements (numbers 1-5 on the table above) moot as having only swords would suffice for the ability. I also split these on two lines as logical equivalent is having 4 rules instead of the 3 initially noted.

Next, you need a table to map the available abilities to the bitmasks which would "unlock" them.

ability_to_bitmasks

```
  ability_id   bitmask_id
  8            1
  8            2
  8            3
  8            4
  8            5
  8            6
  8            7
```

Now you would simply have a bitmask of all abilities your character currently has with which you could compare against the bitmask table to see which rules are satisfied.  The query might look like this:

```
SELECT bitmask_id FROM ability_bitmasks WHERE bitmask & [your character's input bitmask] != 0
```

Or to take it a step further, you could get the eligible abilities via JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.ability_id AS ability_id,
a.name AS name,
a.cost AS cost
FROM ability AS a
INNER JOIN ability_to_bitmasks AS atb on a.ability_id = atb.ability_id
INNER JOIN ability_bitmasks AS ab on atb.bitmask_id = ab.bitmask_id
WHERE ab.bitmask & [your character's input bitmask] != 0
```

So say you have a character with abilities - sword, potions, and archery.  The bitmask would be:

```
101001
```

A query using this bitmask would trigger bitmask ID's 3, 5, and 6 which all have references to ability id 8.

Also note that you can use an integer field instead of a bit field if you like (with values 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...) and use bitwise comparison on the integers.  This might actually be easier to work with from in data management standpoint.  I simply chose to use bit fields in this example, as hopefully it illustrates the usage a little better.

Comment: Is there a kind of index which makes working with bitmasks like this more efficient in MySQL? What you're doing now is basically the integer version of `like`.

Comment: @GolezTrol Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support bitmap indexes, which is what would be ideal for this situation.  As such, the use of index should be tested as it may be spotty, or need to be forced depending on the cardinality of the data.  Certainly, if the data size is not large, one could also consider a memory table here if the index performance is not as desired.  Luckily my guess is that, for this use case, the number of rows of data should be relatively small.

Comment: And what about Archery && 3 of the following(Ability 1,Ability 2,Ability 3,Ability 4,Ability 5,Ability 6) prerequisite?
How could i represent this with a bitmask?

Comment: @MetalMario Sorry I guess I didn't fully explain how you might do such combinations.  You would likely need to make a number of bitmask to represent each cmobination (i.e. `archery + abl 1 + abl 2 + abl 3`, `archery + abl 1 + abl 2 + abl 4`, `archery + abl 1 + abl 2 + abl 5`, `archery + ab 1 + abl 2 + abl 6`, `archery + abl 2 + abl 3 + abl 4`, etc.)  This might seem a little repetitive, but luckily you only need to do this once per set of possible combinations, and unless you start getting into hundreds of abilities, with lots of combos, your bitmask table should remain reasonably sized.

Comment: @MetalMario The other thing you could certainly do is build a simple UI for configuring bitmasks if you find you will be doing this sort of thing frequently. It might be useful to maintain a "notes" field in your bitmap table to have human-readable explanations for each.

Comment: I think that the bitmask is too hard for my use case...my platform must be versatile, i do not know which abilities are inside the RPG, the game master should add every ability accorting to his RPG...would be hard to calculate bitmasks

Comment: @MetalMario If you are looking for versatility, I think the bitmask approach would be your ally rather than a roadblock.  By using this approach, you don't have to make schema modifications to accommodate new abilities, new ability combos, etc. You would likely just need to provide a UI as mentioned before to build the bitmasks for you.  The alternative is likely to store a set of abilities and a set of rules in the DB, then download all of them and brute force the ability calculation each time this functionality is called. This may mean you need code changes to implement new combination logic

Answer (score 0):

What about expressions?
I would store in the prerequisites table strings to represent prerequisites.
For example:

```
14 && 15 && 16 would represent "i need every ability with a certain ID"
14 && 3(15,16,17,19,20,21) would represent "i need ability 14 and 3 of the following abilities.
```

Then, using PHP, i could check the prerequisite parsing the string at runtime.

Comment: The downside to this is changing your prerequisite tree. In the second case, if you decided ability with id 18 was a more important prereq than ability 19, you have to pull in the whole expression, parse it, replace 19 with 18, and then save it out to the database again. Further, reverse-lookups are much harder: what abilities have 19 as a prereq? To do this you have to pull in the ENTIRE table, parse it and then decide programmatically.

Comment: @MetalMario  I don't even really understand what you are getting at here. How are you going to evaluate the string at runtime? I mean certainly you could store a rule like `14 && 15 && 16` in string format in MySQL and then download the entire rule set and evaluate against each one in PHP at run-time, but this seems like a very CPU (and possibly memory) intensive operation when there are other alternatives. Basically at that point you are implementing a brute force solution in PHP, which is of course always an option.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about using two tables.

The first

```
Prereq_expression

|Ability ID(references the ability)| Expression|
```

Would contain the ID of the ability and the expression to get it(as i showed in the previous answer).

The second:

```
Prereq

|Ability ID(references the ability)|Prereq ID(references the needed ability)|
```

With this approach(redundance) i could easily answer " What abilities have ability with ID 20 as prerequisite?" querying the second table, while i could evaluate the requirements parsing expression in the first table.

However, this requires the consistence between the two tables, but, in my platform, changing an ability requirements means "the game master has changed the rulebook", which is a very rare operation...
What do you think about?